# How to change biblatex-GOST styles?

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies

How can i make my bibliography have this style?

```
[3names, et al. if needed], [article name]. // [journal]. [Year]. – V. [volume]. – I. [issue]. – P. [page].
```

Style do differ for russian and english language but not that much (see item 3):
V. changes to Т., I. changes to В.  P. changes to С.

> 1. McCarthy G.J., White W.B., Pfoertsch D.E., Synthesis of nuclear waste monazites, ideal actinide hosts for geologic disposal. // Materials research bulletin. 1978. – V. 13. – I. 11. – P. 1239.
> 2. Doroshenko J., Zurkova J., Moravec Z., et al., Sonochemical precipitation of amorphous uranium phosphates from trialkyl phosphate solutions and their thermal conversion to UP2O7. // Ultrasonics Sonochemistry. 2015. – V. 26. – P. 1.
> 3. Кобец Л.В., Умрейко Д.С. // Успехи химии. 1983. - Т. 52. - В. 6. - С. 897.

Comment: Would you be able to show us what you have so far? A MWE ([MWEB](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/4407/35864)) with some bibliography entries would really help so we can test our ideas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without MWE it's difficult to understand what your troubles are but if you use `biblatex-gost` and want to change the delimiter between volumes, issues etc. in `@article`, you probably need this redefinition:

```
\renewbibmacro*{jour:volume+parts+issuetitle}{%
  \printfield{volume}%
  \newblock
  \printfield{issue}%
  \newblock
  \printfield{number}%
  \iffieldundef{issuetitle}
    {}
    {\newblock
     \printfield{issuetitle}}}%
```

This won't comply with GOST however.